# Is there a single word that means "strange object"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As stated by title, I was wondering if there's any noun that means "strange object".

For example, it would be something like this:

> He found many [xxx] in the abandoned house.

Comment: UFO! kidding. *Oddment* is another.

Comment: I know this is going to sound boring but "strange things" does the job.  All the words suggested below are inaccurate.  Curios are trinkets and knick knacks that you'd find in an antique store, junk shop, thrift store.  When you say strange things, what are you thinking of...was the house the scene of a bizarre crime?  Is it haunted or the home of zombies?  Did Doc Brown live there?  Knowing that would help narrow the search for a more apt word...otherwise, we're just searching blind.

Comment: @Mrstupid Perhaps USO (Unidentified Sitting Object)? =P

Comment: @Mrstupid As are, of course, _nitwit_, _blubber_, and _tweak_. ;-)

Comment: @MikeKellogg what if the unidentified object is not in the sitting position anymore? :P

Comment: I really don't think this request is specific enough to single out one specific correct answer. Strange in what way? Objects? Any kind of object?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**oddity**

> : a strange or unusual person or thing

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oddity)

Comment: If somebody said they found "many oddities in the abandoned house" I'm not thinking of objects. I'm thinking of doors at crook angles, weird ghost sounds, nonstandard fasteners, and so on. Odd aspects of the house. The full definition includes 'traits'.

Answer (score 31):

[curio](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curio)

> A rare, unusual, or intriguing object [ODO]

He found many curios in the abandoned house.

Comment: Indeed!  :)  : )  : )  : )

Comment: I don't think this has quite the right sense. A curio is not just strange, but also interesting and generally collectible.

Comment: @mattdm agreed...both of them did not check the synonyms for this word.

Comment: *Oddity* is definitely the better word. I didn't check a thesaurus. Let that be a valuable lesson for us all.

Answer (score 24):

The word **curiosity** can also be used for that.

> **curiosity**: [countable] someone or something that is interesting because they are
>   unusual or strange:
>
> *a house full of old maps and other curiosities*

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/curiosity))

In your case:

> He found many curiosities in the abandoned house.

Answer (score 7):

**Anomaly** and its variants could be used here.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anomaly):

> something that is unusual or unexpected : something anomalous

He found many [**anomolies**] in the abandoned house.

Comment: Personally, I think of anomalies as being events or properties more than concrete objects.

Answer (score 5):

curio

He found many curios in the abandoned house.

> [curio](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curio) ˈkjʊərɪəʊ   noun   a rare, unusual, or intriguing object.
>   "they had such fun over the wonderful box of curios that Jack had sent
>   from India"
>
> [ODO]

Comment: Did you check the synonyms for curio?

Answer (score 4):

In your question the intensity and nature of the strangeness is unclear. Possibilities for "strange objects" include:

### [tchotchke](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCYQFjACahUKEwjR9cb5pdnIAhVC4SYKHW0vDaE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTchotchke&usg=AFQjCNHrRHZwvyp1T9tcDfuYsEsQuiS_7A&sig2=dtmm9hIPrkeG8tycZvTg4g&bvm=bv.105841590,d.eWE&cad=rja)

A tchotchke (/ˈtʃɒtʃkə/ CHOCH-ka) is a small bauble or miscellaneous item. The word has long been used by Jewish-Americans and in the regional speech of New York City and elsewhere. The word may also refer to free promotional items dispensed at trade shows, conventions, and similar large events.

---

### [bric-a-brac](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bric-a-brac)

miscellaneous small articles collected for their antiquarian, sentimental, decorative, or other interest.

---

### [knickknack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/knickknack)

A small worthless object, especially a household ornament.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps [*artifact*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact)? since someone already suggested *tchotchke*

Answer (score 2):

Good words are: **thingamabob** or **thingamajig**

"You want thingamabobs?
I've got twenty!"
- Ariel (The Little Mermaid)

Answer (score 1):

dingus

noun, plural dinguses. Informal.
1. a gadget, device, or object whose name is unknown or forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

- *Oddity* or *curiosity* fits best in the context of the sample sentence.
- In a lighthearted context, *bizarrerie*.
- In an awe-inspiring sense, *wonder* or *marvel*.
- In a Biblical or Lovecraftian sense, *abomination,* the latter
  usually modified by eldritch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these for **strange object**

- *prodigy*
- *antique*
- *rarity*

and of-course those mentioned above but these are more suitable in your context.

Comment: [**prodigy**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prodigy): *an amazing or unusual thing, especially one out of the ordinary course of nature.* synonyms: *genius, mastermind, virtuoso, wunderkind, wonder child, boy wonder, girl wonder, whiz kid, whiz wizard* In other words, it doesn't fit, and neither does *antique*.

Comment: and what about rarity?

Comment: I would look up that word in a dictionary and check its meaning, if I were you; does it mean: *weird*, *odd*, *peculiar*, *unfamiliar*, *unusual*, *oddball*, or *strange*?

Answer (score 0):

alien.  all objects are unknown to someone

Comment: Hi and welcome. The OP gave a context; in that context the answer wouldn't work (too much associated with space creatures.)

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the Douglas Adams style "He found many perfectly normal things in the abandoned house that weren't."

Answer (score 0):

If you care about ancient words, there are *mirabilia* and *thaumata*, with a notion of wonder, see for instance page 4 of Matthew Leigh [From Polypragmon to Curiosus: Ancient Concepts of Curious and Meddlesome behaviour](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780199668618.do), with a preview available at Google books.